# not able to install skype

Tags: apt, software-installation, skype

I am getting the following error while trying to install skype

```
Failed to download repository information
check your internet connection

E:The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E:The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security Release' does no longer have a Release file.
W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E:The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety Release' does no longer have a Release file.
W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E:The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports Release' does no longer have a Release file.
W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E:The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates Release' does no longer have a Release file.
```

Comment: It looks like you are using Ubuntu 16.10. It has reached it's end of life. It is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Ubuntu Yakkety Yak (16.10) which is out of support and EOL (End of Life).

You need to upgrade to a newer Ubuntu Version.
As Ubuntu 16.10 will Upgrade to 17.04, which is also EOL you need to upgrade to 17.10.

You can do so by executing `sudo do-release-upgrade`.